# CE Amplifier voltage gain is not as calculated

Tags: amplifier, oscilloscope, gain, multisim

Am trying to learn from what i read by simulating a common-emitter-amplifier using 2N3055A that has **Bdc**(DC Current Gain) of 20 - 70. I fallowed the steps below but the Voltage gain is not even close to what i calculated 144 and what the oscilloscope showed 44.3. What am i missing or doing wrong.

The setup was to have IE=0.02A.

[image]

Step 1: DC calculations

```
VE = 0.1VCC = 0.9V
RE = VE / IE = 0.9/0.02 = 45
RC = 4*RE = 180
R2 < Bdc*0.01*RE => R2 = 9
V2 = VE + 0.7 = 1.6V
V1 = VCC - V2 = 7.4V
R1 = R2*(V1/V2) = 42
```

Step 2: Capacitor calculations

```
CE < 0.1*RE = 4.5 => CE=1/(2*PI*4.5*F) =35.3uf
CB < 0.1*R1||R2 = 0.74 => CB =1/(2*PI*0.74*F) =215uf
CC < 0.1*RLoad = 1000=> CC = 1/(2*PI*1000*F) = 159nf
```

Step 3: Voltage Gain calculations

```
r'e = 25mV/ IE = 1.25
rc = RC || RLoad = 177
Av(voltage gain) = rc/ r'e = 141
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Hint:  Note that, for a CE amplifier, the voltage gain is negative (the input and output are in anti-phase).  Looking at your 'scope trace, this isn't the case.

Comment: Another hint: you should consider what the effect of R1 and R2 will be on the signal voltage at the base of the transistor. Think Thevenin equivalent.

Comment: I appreciate you giving me hints, but i don't understand why you did not just show what am doing wrong. I fallowed the design guideline that requires that R1||R2 <= 0.01*HFE*RE = 9, and if i used Rth and Vth to get R1 = 50, R2 = 11 together R1||R2 = 9, then for the cap CB <= 0.1*R1||R2||Rin(base) were Rin(base)= hfe *r'e = 18.7 (2N3055A hfe = 15) but this did not  fix the anti-phase or the Av calculation. When i used a swamped RE2 with a value 10r'e it fixed the anti-phase but the Av = (RC||Rload)/RE2 is still wrong. Thank you and sorry for all the complication

Comment: *"but i don't understand why you did not just show what am doing wrong"* Of course you don't.

Comment: "Of course you don't", lol that was strong thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the circuit as drawn, the emitter capacitor has an impedance (magnitude) of

$$|Z_{C_E}| = \frac{1}{2\pi \cdot 1\mathrm{kHz}\cdot35\mu F} \approx 4.5 \Omega$$

at \$1\mathrm{kHz}\$ so your calculation of the gain isn't correct.

A more correct calculation of the gain at this frequency is

$$|A_v| = \left| \frac{R_C||R_L}{r_e + R_E||Z_{C_E}}\right| \approx 36.7  $$

According to the 'scope screen capture, the gain (magnitude) is about 33.5.

For your calculation to be correct, the capacitor impedance, at the frequencies of interest, must be much less than \$r_e\$.